# Bamboo CI - how to run a test script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, vbscript, bamboo

using bamboo CI, is there a way to call my test script which is a bat file that runs some vbscript commands to perform the tests?
thanks,
B.

Answer (score 1):

In the build step you can add a Script Task.
In the Script body you can call the bat file by
`"path to ur bat file/ur file.bat" arguments/options`